# Inner joining twice returns no result

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've two tables named nodes, and links, like so:

```
--Links:
-----------------------------------
id    fromx   fromy    tox     toy
-----------------------------------
a1      x1      y1      x2      y2
a2      x2      y2      x3      y3
a3      x2      y2      x4      y4
a4      x1      y1      x4      y4
a5      x1      y1      x5      y5

--Nodes:
id       x   y
--------------
1       x1  y1
2       x2  y2
3       x3  y3
4       x4  y4
5       x5  y5
```

I'd like to produce a third table by matching the fromx, fromy, and tox, toy in the Links table against the x and y in the Nodes table to produce a table like so:

```
linkid  fromid  toid
--------------------
  a1     1       2
  a2     2       3
  a3     2       4
  a4     1       4
  a5     1       5
```

In an effort to get to that result, I used this query to join twice on the nodes table using the following query, but I get no results.

```
select links.id as linkid, 
n1.id as nodeid, fromx, fromy, tox from links 
inner join nodes n1 
inner join nodes n2
on 
links.fromx = n1.x 
and  links.fromy = n1.y
and links.tox = n2.x
and links.toy = n2.y
```

I"m happy to create a temp table or such, if that would help.

Comment: This is an interesting problem. I'm recreating your data, but I only have access to SQL Server right now, so I'll play around with syntax that is as standard as possible.

Comment: As the others suggested, it is most probably related to your data. If you run the command line SQLite shell (sqlite3.exe on Windows), you can use ".dump" to generate SQL statements to generate all create table and insert into statements. If you add that output to your question. Others can reproduce your schema and data.

Answer (score 3):

```
select 
       l.id as link_id, 
       frm.id as from_id, 
       t.id as to_id
from  
       links l
inner join 
       nodes frm
       on frm.x = l.fromx
       and frm.y = l.fromy
inner join 
       nodes t
       on t.x = l.tox
       and t.y = l.toy
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43a1c8/6)

Comment: Thank you very much! This unfortunately is not working in sqlite though, and I've no idea why. (I'm using SQLiteStudio to test it). The query returns nothing when run in it. :(

Comment: I used essentially the same query in SQL Server and got the correct result.

Comment: @PatJones I fully understand, the jophab has also posted a link to SQL Fiddle where it runs alright on MySql. I suppose it has to do with SQLite then?

Comment: There must be a very subtle syntactic difference here. When I duplicate my `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements on SQL Fiddle using SQLite, it just hangs while trying to build the schema...

Comment: @VadaPoché The syntax for join is same for  both sqllite and mysql. I am not sure about the create and insert syntax. So just try running the code of join after creating the table using correct subtax o sqlite

Comment: @jophab I try to join after the table has been created and populated, but there are no results. Many thanks for helping though. I at least now know of one way to solve the problem, and will just have to figure out why this isn't working now.

Comment: @VadaPoché Make sure the data is correct. ie check for trailing and leading spaces  in character columns. May be that is causing the problem

Comment: I'd agree that there is something off with the data itself that is causing this not to work. My SQL Fiddle (SQL Server) is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c77c42/1).

Comment: @PatJones Just checked: the SQL from your SQL Fiddle works fine when using SQLite directly - maybe there is a problem on the My SQL Fiddle website.